# How do I perform an action only when a specific UIViewController is dismissed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a controller and it is presented this way:

```
- (void)searchButtonTapped
{
    NSLog(@"search button tapped");
    VAGSearchViewController *svc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchPageSB"];

    [self presentViewController:svc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The controller that presents it is a collectionView controller. What I want to do is have this collectionView know when this searchViewController was dismissed so I can perform an action.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Please note this action needs to only be performed when the searchViewController is dismissed.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I think there is a search delegate

Comment: Checked already and there isn't a searchbar or searchdisplaycontroller delegate I can use for this issue.

Comment: How the searchViewController is dismissed? You could write a protocol, say SearchViewControllerDelegate, and after the searchViewController is dismissed it would call [self.delegate searchViewControllerDismissed];

Comment: It's dismissed in the didSeledtRowAtIndexPath method.  When a row is tap I need a specific query to run on the collection view controller after the search controller is dismissed. Delegation may just work. I will give that a try.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
and 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own delegate for this.

In VAGSearchViewController.h

```
@class VAGSearchViewController;
@protocoll VAGSearchViewControllerDismissDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) searchViewControllerDismissed:(VAGSearchViewController*)searchViewController;
@end

//VAGSearchViewController Interface
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<VAGSearchViewControllerDismissDelegate> dismissDelegate;
```

Call the method on the delegate when you dismiss the viewController

```
[self.dismissDelegate searchViewControllerDismissed:self];
```

And in your collectionViewController add the protocoll

```
@interface MyCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <VAGSearchViewControllerDismissDelegate>
```

Implement the didDismiss method and assign self as a delegate when presenting the searchViewController:

```
- (void)searchButtonTapped
{
    NSLog(@"search button tapped");
    VAGSearchViewController *svc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchPageSB"];
    svc.dismissDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void) searchViewControllerDismissed:(VAGSearchViewController*)searchViewController{
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Seemed like the best way to do it but thought there would be an easier way than delegation but this worked fine.